# Gene expression data in hashes

Tags: regex, perl

I have two data files: one contains gene expression data, the other genome annotation data. I have to compare values in columns 1 and 2 of one file and if 1 > 2 then output that line as well as the refseq id found on the same line of the annotation data file.

So far I have opened both files for reading:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open (my $deg, "<", "/data/deg/DEG_list.txt") or die $!;
open (my $af "<", "/data/deg/Affy_annotation.txt") or die $!;

# I want to store data in hash

my %data;
while (my $records = <$deg>) {
  chomp($records);

  # the first line is labels so we want to skip this
  if($records =~ /^A-Z/) {
    next;
  else {
    my @columns = split("/\s/", $records);

    if ($columns[2] > $columns[1]) {
      print $records;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to print the line every time this happens, but I also want to print the gene id which is found in the other data file. I'm not sure how to do this, plus the code I have now is not working, in that it doesn't just print the line.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your code has stray brackets. Please confirm that this is not the issue.

Comment: `split` takes a regex as first argument, without extra quotes. Or use the string `' '` (single space) which splits on all whitespace. Also, columns are numbered starting with `0` (not one-based).
— If it doesn't work after following Zaids and my suggestions, please provide example data and expected output, so that we can test for ourself.

Comment: You should give some sample input and expected output

Answer (score 1):

Besides your missing parentheses here and there, your problem is probably your regex

```
if($records =~ /^A-Z/) {
```

This looks for lines that begin with this literal string, e.g. `A-Zfoobar`, and not, as you might be thinking, any string beginning with a capital letter. You probably want:

```
if($records =~ /^[A-Z]/) {
```

The square brackets denote a character class with a range inside.

You should also know that `split /\s/, ...` splits on a single whitespace, which may not be what you want, in that it creates empty fields for every extra whitespace you have. Unless you explicitly want to split on a single whitespace, you probably want

```
split ' ', $records;
```

Which will split on multiple consecutive whitespace, and strip leading whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Two main problems in the code

```
if($records =~ /^A-Z/) ...
```

if you want to detect letters at the beginning of a line, you better

```
if($records =~ /^[a-z]/i) ... starting with any letter
if($records =~ /^[A-Z]/) ...  starting with big letter
```

And in

```
my @columns = split("/\s/", $records);
```

the regex is here a string ... (since quoted), to have a regex remove the quotes

```
my @columns = split(/\s/, $records);
```

but if you want to split fields even if there is more than one space, use

```
my @columns = split(/\s+/, $records);
```

instead.